# Can I define a map whose key is a structure?

Tags: c++, data-structures, stl, dictionary

and how can I do it in C++?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use any type as a map key, as long as it implements an `operator<` (plus the usual copy-and-assign requirements for values stored in containers).

For instance:

```
struct example { int x; }

bool operator < (const example &l, const example &r) { return l.x < r.x; }

std::map<example, int> values;
```

Alternatively, you may provide a comparison function as the third argument of the map template instead of defining `operator<`. More details [here](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Map.html) (parameter `Compare`).

Comment: "as long as it implements an operator<" - or there's a specialization of `std::less` for the type. `map` uses `less` by default, and `less` uses `operator<` by default, so there are two routes in.