# overloading of < operator not called when using struct as key in map?

Tags: c++, dictionary, operator-overloading

I have understood that we have to write the operator overloading function for < operator when we have using the key as struct since the map uses the strict week ordering it has to compare before inserting in to map.

Hope my understanding is correct by reading from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3935681/can-i-define-a-map-whose-key-is-a-structure).

consider the following snippet

```
  struct Node
    {
       int a;     

     };


    // This is not called

  bool operator< (const Node &p_node1,const Node &p_node2)
  {
       printf("\nCALLED OPERATOR OVERLOADING");
       return true;
  }

    int main()
    {
       using namespace std;        
       map<Node,int> my_map;        
       Node n1;
       n1.a=55;

       my_map[n1]=2; // operator overloading should be called

       return 0;
    }
```

And the issue is operator overloading function not called?

EDIT:

From the answer below, After adding the one more pair to container operator overloading is called.
But why it is called three times specifically, what is compared here?

Answer (score 6):

When the map is empty, the comparator does not need to be invoked because there is nothing to compare against to.

Comment: You were correct. After adding one more pair to container the overloaded operator function < is called three times. what is behind the scene?

Comment: In my tests it is just used once. The map internally is a binary search tree, so, every comparison should direct the search to one or other side of the tree. In average case, you should have log2(N) comparisons (where N is the number of elements in the map) before finding (or not) the element you are looking for.

Comment: Just have a look at snippet posted by shiva kumar. Here also it is called three times http://ideone.com/iGY9Xa

Comment: I am using clang 3.3 (using the shiva kumar code) and it just compares once.

Comment: Am using gcc It is also comparing three times

Answer (score 2):

You are inserting the only element in an empty map and so the comparison operator is never called. Try having more than one element in `my_map`.

Answer (score 0):

Have atleast 2 elements in map for comparison operator to be called.

```
       Node n1;
       n1.a=55;

       my_map[n1]=2; // operator overloading should be called

       Node n2;
       n2.a=55;

       my_map[n2]=3;
```

See below modified example code.

http://ideone.com/iGY9Xa